# What constitutes the start of a basic block?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

Does the instruction following an unconditional jump in assembly code constitute the start of a new basic block? Let's say that instruction is not the target of any branch in the executable.

Comment: Is it meaningful to analyze assembly code to try to locate blocks?

Comment: That instruction can not be reached in any normal way (except by jumping halfway into the preceding unconditional jump and hoping things work) so in some ways it's not even "code" at all, just data.

Comment: @CarlNorum - Yes, it is. Reconstructing a CFG whose nodes are basic blocks is one of the first steps in static binary analysis.

Comment: Define "basic block". Assembly "blocks of code" can be however you wish to logically define them. In and of itself, assembly language doesn't have a defined block structure.

Comment: "In computing, a basic block is a portion of the code within a program with certain desirable properties that make it highly amenable to analysis. Compilers usually decompose programs into their basic blocks as a first step in the analysis process. Basic blocks form the vertices or nodes in a control flow graph." - Wikipedia

Comment: By that definition, an unconditional jump may or may not form a "basic block" depending upon what the code is doing and why it is jumping. Phrases such as "desirable" and "highly amenable" are a little subjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the possibility of calculated branches, and conditional branches possibly always or never being followed, it is impossible to perfectly determine what constitutes a basic block. Instead, basic blocks are estimated using two assumptions:

1. Calculated branches will only go to a location which is the beginning of a basic block for some other reason, and therefore their targets do not need to be known.
2. Conditional branches can be both followed and not followed.

Using [Wikipedia's definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block#Definition), a basic block can only be entered at the beginning and exited at the end, with exactly one path from beginning to end. Therefore, any conditional jump instruction must be the end of a basic block, as it creates two paths. Calculated branches are also the end, since they can produce many different paths.

Whether an unconditional jump is the end of a basic block can be debated using slightly different definitions. If all of the code in a block must be sequential in memory, then an unconditional jump is always the end, unless it goes to the instruction after it. Otherwise, it follows the same rules as non-jump instructions.

For all other instructions, if the instruction which would be executed after it is the start of a basic block, then it must be the end of one.

The easiest start of a block is the entry point of the program. Additionally, any instruction which is the target of a conditional jump is the start of a block, since it may or may not be executed after the jump instruction. If an instruction is the target of an unconditional jump and basic blocks must be sequential in memory, then it is the start of a block. Otherwise, if it is the target of two or more unconditional jumps, or it is the target of one and the instruction before it is not an unconditional jump, it is the start of a block as there are multiple paths into it.

If the instruction after an unconditional jump is not the target of any other jump, it may still be labeled as the beginning of a basic block, since its existence suggests a calculated branch may target it.

These rules for the start of a basic block essentially simplify to "the instruction executed after the end of a basic block is the start of a basic block".

A much simpler method which may sometimes produce smaller blocks, but is generally good, is that any jump is the end of a block, and the instruction after it is the start of one, while the target of any jump is the start of a block and the instruction before it is the end of one.

---

If there is higher-level code available, it can be used to determine block boundaries more accurately. For example, compiler-generated calculated branches will often have a known set of  possible targets. Consider the following C code:

```c
int i, j, k;
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        j++;
        // Flow into the next case
    case 1:
        k++;
}
```

Here is some possible pseudo-assembly for this code using a calculated branch:

```
jump    *(i+jumpTable)
add     1, j
add     1, k
```

The jump table will target one of the add instructions, so they are both the start of a basic block. This cannot be determined from the assembly, though, so the first assumption is used. The first add is the start of a basic block, since it comes after a jump. But, there is no known branch targeting the second add, so it is not considered the start of a basic block by this analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Instruction that follows unconditional jump and is not a target of of any branch or jump is dead code or simply data.

Comment: Figuring that out can be tough, since jump destinations can be embedded in jump tables or even calculated on the fly.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch - Exactly. Sometimes it can be difficult or impossible to generate a complete CFG from an executable using purely static methods.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch - I am fully agree. It is always not trivial task to analyze an executable code and to guess what is data and what is code itself.